# Access-Control-Allow-Origin refuses to work with angularjs / C# WEB API

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am hoping someone can help me solve this problem with CORS. I have a custom header that I am try to return to an angularjs client that is always null. I can't understand what is missing from this.

In my web.config:

```
  <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
```

also tried:

```
 <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Etag" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
```

In the WebApiConfig.cs

```
            // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also have tried adding the following attribute to the controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Etag", methods: "*")]
```

The code in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody]Container args)
    {
        //Do stuff with args
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Headers.Add("Bar", Bar); 
        return response;
    }
```

My Angularjs call:

```
return $http({
        url: "http://localhost:xxxxx/API/Foo/{args}",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            var bar = response.headers('Bar'); //ALWAYS NULL!
        }
        else {
            //Do other stuff
        }
    }, function (response) {
        //handle error
     });
```

No matter what I have tried, The value for 'Bar" always comes back as null in Angularjs. The value does show up in proxies like Fiddler. Can someone tell me what is missing?

**Update:**

```
console.log(response.headers('Bar')); //Prints the expected value out to the console. 

 var bar = response.headers('Bar'); //Still gives me a null.
```

What is the difference between printing to the console and assigning to a variable? I even tried renaming the 'bar' variable to something else in case it was a scope problem. Still showed up as null!

**Update 2:**

It seems to be having a problem assigning to the var. If I do something like the following, it will work.

```
var getHeaderValue = function(x) { return x; } 
var bar = getHeaderValue(response.headers('Bar')); //bar contains the expected value and is no longer null.
```

Comment: try consoling out all the headers: `console.log(response.headers());`. and let us know what you see.

Comment: @GPicazo I see a bunch of things, including 'bar' (lowercase b instead of upper case 'B' as I would expect. When trying to use response.headers('bar'); I still get a null value.

Comment: Can you try to console it out: `console.log(response.headers('Bar'));` ?

Comment: @GPicazo it shows the value as expected.

Comment: that doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you try: `var bar = response.headers('Bar'); console.log(bar);`?

Comment: @GPicazo That gives me the null value. You are right, none of this makes any sense.. that is why I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127067/discussion-between-gpicazo-and-dave).